# Return observable depending on another observable condition

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, store

I need to return observable of data depending on some condition of another observable, so if the ids in the store are different send the updated data to the outer observable if no don't send any updates, I need this feature to support multi-tab, so each tab has its own loading and not affecting the other one,
So this code will return data only if the `search_id` changed, what should we return in the outer observable in case there is no change???

```
       this.data$ = this.getTopData$('book').pipe(
        map(data => {
               this.store
              .select(currentSearchSelector)
              .pipe(bufferCount(2))
             .subscribe(([previousSearch, currentSearch]) => {
             if ( previousSearch.id !== currentSearch.id ) {

               return data;
             }else
              {
               //what should I return here?
              }

             })
            })    
        ),
```

If I return data as is, the widgets in other tabs will feel the change and load it's own data anytime other tabs changes their search.

Answer (score 0):

I tidied the code up a little bit, you can use `never()` to not emit anything to the stream and hence no update on the view.

```
this.getTopData$('book').pipe(
        switchMap(data =>this.store.select(currentSearchSelector).pipe(bufferCount(2))),
        switchMap(([previousSearch, currentSearch]) => {
             if ( previousSearch.id !== currentSearch.id ) {
               return of(data);
               }
              else return never()
       }})
       ).subscribe()
```

Comment: see that never() is replace by conts NEVER in Rxjs 6: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/deprecations

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but data inside the second switchMap is not defined